# gvim: Colour lines differently containing TODO/HACK/etc?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Often I'll put comments in code like TODO/HACK/BUG: I'd love if these showed up glaringly when I did a diff of the code in vim.

Is there an easy way to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a syntax group like this:

```
:syntax match TODOs ".*TODO.*\|.*BUG.*\|.*HACK.*"
```

This will match entire lines which contain either `TODO`, `BUG` or `HACK` in them.

Then you can use the `highlight` command to highlight it.

```
:highlight TODOs ctermbg=red ctermfg=yellow term=bold,italic
```

You can add both the lines to your `vimrc` or the syntax file for appropriate file types.